# wordpress responsive extended menu do not work

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, responsive

http://tracirochester.staging.wpengine.com/

On the site everything works fine on mobile view except that the responsive extended menu is not displaying.

If you view on mobile, the submenu under 
**Courses > Specialist consultancy ‘Bridge workshops’** 
is not showing on mobile.

I am not sure what css class I have to target to show the extended menu.

This site is built using `Beaver Page Builder` but this is using the wordpress menu (not the menu module).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 3 submenu items do show. 
They're just immediately expanded. 
Even in your screenshot that you provided, you can see that they already show. 
<s>Maybe try and look to see if the beaver page builder has settings to fix this?</s>

[image: screenshot]

---

**EDIT:**
I take back what I said. 
Just add `margin-left` to your already expanded submenus.

```
.sub-menu .sub-menu {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: You are the man! I did not notice that oh my.. i must have been so sleepy. you are a star @Rickey Dam!

Comment: @LeeDev No worries! Glad I could help out! Keep on coding!